# Get the raw text from a string(source: excel, database)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I acquire text form excel files and database.

The text has in it "invisible" characters, i presume like new lines, carriage return, non breaking text, tabs etc.

If I print the text or check, python interprets the text, but I want to get the raw text as it is.

Comment: What "acquires" the text? you need to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [repr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
a = '\r\n'
print(a)
#
#
print(repr(a))
#'\r\n'
```